# get table column value of selected row in table asp.net in jQuery

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-3

I am working on asp.net mvc project.

I want to get the cell value from the selected row (row in which "Manage "button is clicked).
in this case value of userID.

```
<table width="100%" class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover" id="dataTables-example">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th width="45%">User ID</th>
        <th width="45%">User Name</th>
        <th width="5%">View</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    @foreach (var item in Model.TypeList)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.UserId)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.UserName)
            </td>
            <td>
                <input id="Manage2" class="btn btn-primary" type="button" value="Manage" />
            </td>
        </tr>
    }
</tbody>
```

I am calling jQuery click function and Ajax call and want to send the UserId value in data from selected row to the controller.

below is the jQuery ajax call,

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function () {
      $('#Manage2').click(function () {
          //alert(1);

          var url = '@Url.Action("ManageUserRole", "UserRoleCompany")';

          $.ajax({
              url: url,
              data: { Id: '1' },
              cache: false,
              type: "POST",
              success: function (data) {
                  $("#Data").html(data);
              },
              error: function (reponse) {
                  alert("error : " + reponse);
              }
          });
      });
    });

</script>
```

Below is the view screen shot,

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have invalid html because of the duplicate `id` attributes in your button.

Remove the `id="Manage2"` and replace with a class name and `data-` attribute for the value

```
<input data-id="@item.UserId" class="btn btn-primary Manage2" type="button" value="Manage" />
```

Then in the script, get the value using

```
$('.Manage2').click(function () { // class selector
   var id = $(this).data('id);
   var url = '@Url.Action("ManageUserRole", "UserRoleCompany")';
   $.ajax({
      url: url,
      data: { Id: id },
      ....
```

Alternatively you could use relative selectors

```
$('.Manage2').click(function () {
    var id = $(this).closest('tr').children('td:first').text();
    ....
```

Comment: It is only working on the first row of a table and not working on the second row onwards.

Comment: The code I gave works for **all** rows! What are you claiming is not working, and what error are you getting in the browser console?

Comment: When I click the "manage" button from the second row onwards it doesn't hit the jQuery function that's what all I mean. There is no error specific to this in console

Comment: Yes it does if you have used the code I have given. But you appear to have an 'Add' button in your view - is that for adding new rows to your table? And if that is the case, then you need to use event delegation to handle dynamically added elements

Answer (score 1):

You can actually store the UserId value with **html 5 data attribute** on the button itself.

Your current code has `Id` attribute value hard coded inside a loop, which will create more than one element with same `Id` value. That is invalid HTML!

Remove the `Id` and use a more generic selector to wire up the click event. Here I added another CSS class "manage" to the button.

```
<input data-userid="@item.UserId" class="btn btn-primary manage" 
                                  type="button" value="Manage" />
```

and now

```
$(document).ready(function () {    
      $('.manage').click(function () {
         var id = $(this).data("userid");
         alert(id);
         // use id for your ajax call
      });    
});
```

You do not necessarily need to add the extra css class only to use that as the selector later. Since you are adding a `data` attribute, you may simply use that as well for your jQuery selector.

```
$(function () {

    $('[data-userid]').click(function () {
        var id = $(this).data("userid");
        alert(id);
        // use id
    });

});
```